# Exploding string in PHP for converting one part in uppercase and other in lowercase?

Tags: php

Does anybody have idea how to explode some string in PHP, where in example:

```
<?
// Submitted through register form

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

// example $_POST['first_name'] is somebody
// and need to be exploded at position 1 or by letter 'o' in this example
// but that is not always letter o
// I made also 

$first_name_lc = strtolower($first_name);

// converted all to lowers and now
// exploding at letter o

$explode_rule = 'o';

$first_name_lc_exploded = explode($explode_rule, $first_name_lc);

// now in example we have $first_name_lc_exploded[0] and $first_name_lc_exploded[1]
// $first_name_lc_exploded[0] is now 's' and $first_name_lc_exploded[1] is 'mebody'
// now new first name is $first_name_lc_exploded[0].$explode_rule.$first_name_lc_exploded[1]
// but $first_name_lc_exploded[0] need to be converted in upper and only that, nothing else
// than $first_name_lc_exploded[0] is 'S' instead of 's'
// and first_name is now 'Somebody' instead of 'somebody'
?>
```

So now, question is: how to replace letter o with something that looks for the second letter inside of string, and explode it with that rule, some variable. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: balanced the downvote. At least, he shown some effort. And that's to be praised. The rest, is lack of knowledge of PHP native functions, so i want to be nice on that.

Comment: Why the heck do you need that explosion? Stop that terrorism! :D

Comment: I think I would need more comments ;-)

Comment: +1 for showing effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just trying to uppercase the first letter, try `ucfirst(strtolower($first_name));`

If you want to uppercase all letters that occur after spaces, try `ucwords(strtolower($first_name));`;

If you truly want to split the string up on the second letter, then use `substr();` to pull out the portions of the string you want.

Another alternative is to use `preg_split();` and use a regular expression to indicate the shape of the string and how you want it split.

Or, you could always `explode($first_name[1], $first_name, 2));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: ... but for real, `ucfirst` or `ucwords` appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: exactly that!!! sorry man, I am just about one month in php so i really need lot of help :D but anyway, this helped a lot. thanks man!

Comment: There are TONS of built in functions in PHP, so it's understandable that you wouldn't have a complete knowledge of them yet.  I've been doing this for 10 years now and I still occasionally run into random functions that have been there for years that would have helped me out a long time ago that I never knew about.

Answer (score 2):

There's a PHP function existing to make the first letter only Uppercase :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Answer (score 0):

Try [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) ! Why do you want to reinvent the wheel each time

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert the first letter of string in upper. Am I right?

There is pre-build two functions in PHP to do that.

1. [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)
2. [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

check the manuals of it.